# maximum likelihood and OLS - true or false

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, residuals, binary-data

I was wondering about these three accusations, whether they are true or false and why is that?

1. The maximum likelihood estimation maximizes the sum of squared residuals.
2. Maximum likelihood estimation always yields a unique solution (i.e., parameter estimates).
3. It is appropriate to use a binary discrete variable as a dependent variable using OLS.

Thanks for reply! :)

Comment: 1) Do you mean that it minimizes the sum of squares residuals? // It will help to mention what assumptions you’re making about your data. // Please add the self-study tag, read it wiki, and say what progress you’ve made in solving this.

Answer (score 2):

(a) The maximum likelihood estimation maximizes the sum of squared residuals.

False. Maximum likelihood estimation maximizes the sample likelihood function.

(b) Maximum likelihood estimation always yields a unique solution (i.e., parameter estimates).

False. Maximum likelihood estimation only guarantees a unique global maximum when the sample likelihood function is concave.

(c) It is appropriate to use a binary discrete variable as a dependent variable using OLS.

False. OLS with a binary dependent variable would means you are fitting a linear probability model. The crucial drawback of this approach is that the estimated/predicted probability could be less than zero or greater than one.

Comment: Note: 'c' can be reasonably answered either way. To argue true, start by noting that OLS estimation consistently estimates coefficients (presuming the rest of the model is correctly specified) even if individual predictions are off. Most economics texts have some elaboration of this, e.g. Angrist and Pischke. Also, logit coefficients are not comparable given underlying (Y*) heterogeneity.

Comment: @conjugateprior I agree, (c) is an open question as it didn't say anything about the model or data generating process. What's the name (and chapter) of the Angrist and Pischke's textbook you mentioned? Thanks! When you say " OLS estimation consistently estimates coefficients (presuming the rest of the model is correctly specified)", you meant the data is generated by a linear probability model, right? As  from my understanding, OLS is only consistent if the choice probability is linear $E(Y|x)=x'\beta$, and the error term is a bernoulli distribution.

Comment: A&P's book is Mostly Harmless Econometric. It's in ch. 3 someplace iirc. This is a nice treatment with refs: https://www.alexpghayes.com/blog/consistency-and-the-linear-probability-model/